# Pass environment variable to bash script, called from within a function

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, functions

I mean to have:

1. A bash script `scr.sh` that takes positional parameters

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Params = $@"
   echo REMOTE_SERVER=${REMOTE_SERVER}
   ```
2. A bash function `f` defined in another script `scr2.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   f() {
       REMOTE_SERVER=s001
       scr.sh "${@}"
   }
   ```

I would first

```
$ source scr2.sh
```

and then have `f` available for calling at the command line, but *not leaving a trace of what I did with `REMOTE_SERVER`*. For instance, I want

```
$ f par1 par2
par1 par2
s001
$ echo REMOTE_SERVER=${REMOTE_SERVER}
REMOTE_SERVER=
```

(actually, if `REMOTE_SERVER` was set before using `f`, I want it to keep that value). I couldn't attain this last objective. I always end up with `REMOTE_SERVER` set.
I tried using multiline commands separated with a semicolon, enclosing commands inside `f` with parenthesis, but it didn't work.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set a variable only for a command, prefix the assignment to the command:

```
REMOTE_SERVER=s001 scr.sh "${@}"
```

Alternately, use a subshell for the function (then variable assignments won't affect the parent shell). You can create a subshell by wrapping commands in `( ... )` (parentheses), or using parentheses instead of braces for the function body. For example, with:

```
foo () (
    REMOTE_SERVER=s001
)
bar () {
    REMOTE_SERVER=s001
}
foo; echo "REMOTE_SERVER=$REMOTE_SERVER"; bar; echo "REMOTE_SERVER=$REMOTE_SERVER";
```

My output would be:

```
REMOTE_SERVER=
REMOTE_SERVER=s001
```

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
#!/bin/bash
f() {
    (
        REMOTE_SERVER=s001
        scr.sh "${@}"
    )
}
```

works fine.
This is likely equivalent to the accepted answer, with the extra flexibility of including parts of the code inside the local shell and parts outside.